# Hide "Out of Stock" variations WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have one issue with my site. Tryed almost all codes that found on stackoverflow and google, but none of them worked in way i wanted.

To list my configuration:

[image]

and [product configuration](http://teenatees.com/product/brooms-are-for-amateurs/):

[image]

But still variations that is out of stock showing in listing. I have this function, but seems do not make any change.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 
'grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock', 10, 2 );

function grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock( $grey_out, $variation ) {

if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() )
    return false;

return true;
}
```

Any tip how to get this working ?

**EDIT**

I found this code, and seems that is working, but now not updating my images for every variation if code is applyed.

```
function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
return 10; // Enter value that is higher then possible variations.
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 
'custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: how many variations?

Comment: That linked product have 36 variations currently. Some is out of stock, some is in stock. Only out of stock need to hide.